# Cannot read property of undefined Processing.js

Tags: processing.js

I have made an object with the object elevation, yet when a try accessing it using an array, the debugger states it is undefined.

```js
var h = 30;
var disk = function(pos,elv){
    this.pos = pos;
    this.elv = elv;
    rect(56 * pos, 369-pos * h + h, 95, h, 2);
};
var disks = [
    {position:1,
    elevation:1},
    {position:1,
    elevation:2},
    {position:1,
    elevation:3},
    {position:1,
    elevation:4},
    {position:1,
    elevation:5},
    {position:1,
    elevation:6}
];
fill(0, 136, 255);
for(var i = 0; i<= 6; i++){
    var diskNum = disks[i];
    disk(1,diskNum.elevation);
}
};
```

I expected the program to draw the rectangles on top of each other, but the program displays Cannot read property elevation of undefined.
https://www.khanacademy.org/computer-programming/new-program/5983920391094272

Comment: Do note that Processing.js has been discontinued, and you are encouraged to use p5js instead.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans This is an old project now. I have done the shift.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 6 elements in your `disks` array, at indexes 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5.

Then you use this `for` loop to iterate over them:

```
for(var i = 0; i <= 6; i++){
```

Since you're using the `<=` operator, this includes 7 total indexes: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, and 6.

You probably just want the `<` operator instead.

Also note that it doesn't make a ton of sense to store `this.pos` and `this.elv` since you never use them for anything.

When I fix the above error, I see a rectangle. Not quite sure what the program is meant to do, but this at least fixes your error.

Comment: The pos and elv variables was for use later. Should have clarified that in my post. Thanks for your help.